# malloc exception in VS

Tags: c++, c

i am trying to allocate memory for a 2 dimensional array using c and i am getting an exception in visual studio 2008.

```
int Count=16383,N=14;
char **result=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*Count);
for(int i=1;i<=Count;i++)       
    result[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*N);  

Unhandled exception at 0x012e1692 in combination.exe: 0xC0000005: 
Access violation writing location 0x00590000
```

the exception takes place when i is 11272 and i can't understand why!

Comment: I'm fairly sure your for loop should be `for(int i=0; i<Count; i++)` unless I'm mis-understanding something.

Comment: yeah ur right.. but i don't really care coz i was just checking y the exception occurred.thx anyway...

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if you got another error from that loop, you'll be overflowing and potentially writing into memory occupied by other things, potentially vital things

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
char **result=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*Count);
```

should be

```
char **result=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*Count);
```

Comment: also, arrays are `0`-based in C and C++, the `for` loop is wrong.

Comment: aaaah and thats why when i replaced (sizeof(char)*Count); with (sizeof(int)*Count); it worked! since sizeof(char*)=sizeof(int)=4.

Comment: @Mat what do you mean by 0-based?

Comment: It means the start of an array is at index 0, not 1. The 0th item is the first position. So if there are 10 items you would iterate from 0-9.

Comment: the first element is `result[0]`, not `result[1]`. You `for` loop should be counting from 0 to (Count-1).

Answer (score 1):

This is why in C code you should never cast the result of `malloc` and why you should not use type names in `sizeof`. You memory allocations should have looked as follows

```
char **result = malloc(Count * sizeof *result);

for(int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)       
    result[i] = malloc(N * sizeof *result[i]);
```

That way the sizes would be automatically calculated correctly, and your memory allocations would be type-independent.

P.S. You said you are using C. Why is your question tagged [C] and [C++] at the same time?

Comment: Interesting I have not seen that before (Its a long time since I used C). I suppose you learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't cast the result of malloc. It's completely unnecessary, obfuscates your code, and can cover up a potentially serious bug if you've forgotten to include a header that provides a proper prototype (or at least declaration) of `malloc`.

Second, don't multiply by `sizeof(char)`, or `sizeof(whatever_type)` -- instead multiply by `sizeof(*destination_variable)`. Finally, instead of using `<=` in your loop, use `<`. The normal idiom for traversing an array in C is `for (i=0; i<array_size; i++)`:

```
int Count=16383,N=14;

char **result = malloc(Count * sizeof(*result));

for(int i=1;i<Count;i++)
    result[i] = malloc(N * sizeof(*result[i]));
```

This not only fixes the problem you encountered, but prevents it from happening again in the future. For example, let's consider starting from code like this:

```
char **result = malloc(Count * sizeof(char *));

for(int i=1;i<Count;i++)
    result[i] = malloc(N * sizeof(char));
```

Now, you've been told you need to support Unicode, so you change `result` from `char **` to `wchar_t **`:

```
wchar_t **result = malloc(Count * sizeof(char *);

for(int i=1;i<Count;i++)
    result[i] = malloc(N * sizeof(char));
```

But now you have a problem again -- you need to change the `sizeof(char)` to `sizeof(wchar_t)`. You really *should* also change the `sizeof(char *)` to `sizeof(whcar_t *)`, though chances are pretty good that the two will be the same, so you'll be able to get away with that discrepancy.

If you use `sizeof(*result)` and `sizeof(*result[i])`, a change like this gets handled automatically -- everything else is based on the type of `result`, so when you change that type, the other sizes are automatically adjusted to match.

Comment: You do have to cast the result from malloc() if you program in C/C++, as @lina seems to do. If you decide on C, that's different...

Comment: @Bo Persson: IMO, that falls into the "just say no" category. Despite their shared history, most code (including this) that attempts to be compatible with both isn't actually *good* for either one.

Comment: @Bo, as a simple rule there is no such thing as C/C++. This is particularly important because their concepts of dynamic allocation differ fundamentally: use `new/new[]/delete/delete[]` for C++ and `malloc/free` for C.

Comment: @Jens - But the question is still tagged both C and C++, so how do we know what to answer? Perhaps "don't cast the result of malloc" means that we shouldn't use it when casting would be necessary?

Comment: @Bo, exactly it should be "*don't try to use the same code with dynamic allocations in C and C++*". And then "*don't use `malloc` in C++*" and "*don't cast its result*" when in C.